# hibernate cached query not updated when new record inserted

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

We have a EHCache cluster, hibernate and Mysql.

Everything is working almost fine. Criteria searches are being cached and when records are modified on other members of the clusters the cached queries are updated instantly on the other servers.

however, my problem is when new records are inserted. The cached queries on that table do not know about it until the cached query are expired.

I probably have missed something on my EHcache.xml configuration, but I have no idea what could it be.

Any ideas?

EHCache.xml follows:

`

```
<!--<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>-->

<!-- means for cache replication -->

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
    properties="connect=
        TCP(bind_port=10700):
        S3_PING(...):
        MERGE2(max_interval=30000;min_interval=10000):
        FD_SOCK(start_port=0):
        FD(timeout=3000;max_tries=3):
        VERIFY_SUSPECT(timeout=1500):
        BARRIER():
        pbcast.NAKACK(use_mcast_xmit=false;gc_lag=0;retransmit_timeout=300,600,1200,2400,4800;discard_delivered_msgs=true):
        UNICAST(timeout=300,600,1200):
        pbcast.STABLE(stability_delay=1000;desired_avg_gossip=50000;max_bytes=400K):
        pbcast.GMS(print_local_addr=true;join_timeout=300;view_bundling=true):
        FC(max_credits=2M;min_threshold=0.10):
        FRAG2(frag_size=60K):
        pbcast.STREAMING_STATE_TRANSFER()"
    propertySeparator="::" />    

<!-- default query cache to be used for all queries without an explicit cache -->

<cache
    name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="100"
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    statistics="true">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,
        replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true" />
</cache>    

<!-- timestamps of particular last update time to tables -->

<cache
    name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="5000"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    statistics="true">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,
        replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true" />
</cache>

<!-- default cache to use for all cacheable entities without an explicit cache -->

<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        statistics="true">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,
            replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true" />
</defaultCache>
```

`

Comment: It's hard to tell you what you've missed if you don't post the ehcache configuration :)

Comment: matt, there you go, updated with conf.

Comment: I can actually see, using ehcache debug log level, the insertion (put) message being received in the host where the criteria query is cached. But for some reason, the query is not expired.

Comment: and the hibernate configuration?

Comment: While back, we have spent a lot of time trying to get distributed write caching work with Hibernate with no luck.  May be it got so much better over last couple of years but I'd still suggest that you keep plan B. For example, specialized app cache. Memcached or something like that.

Comment: We could evict manually the cached query... or something like that. But my guess is that EHCache must do it, otherwise it is a pain.... will keep in mind your point.

Comment: How do you do the insert? Do you by any chance insert the record though JDBC without going though hibernate?

Comment: You don't specify cache type here. Are you 100% sure you have `read-write` and not `nonstrict-read-write` or sth. On others than a `read-write` cache the data saving may be delayed. Also explicit flush on cache can help. Please, do check that setting.

Comment: One thing to consider is what @joostschouten asked.  The nature of a second level cache provider operating under default cache types will only pull queries from the cache until the cache expires, and the only way the cache will get updated is if you use the same session factory to insert the records.  Adding new records directly to the database via Toad (or similar gui app), or using JDBC will not go through nhibernate, and therefore will not add records to your second level cache.

Comment: I am inserting with Hibernate session.save(object). Strategy is Read_Write.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid it's a little too late for the author, but I thought my answer can be useful for anyone else with the same problem.

You should remember how the `StandardQueryCache` and the `UpdateTimestampsCache` work. When the query cache is checked for a query, the time the query was cached is compared to the timestamps of the last update of all tables in the query. If any tables were updated after the query was cached, the cached result gets discarded and the database is used instead. Timestamps of the last update for each table are stored in the `UpdateTimestampsCache`.

In the above configuration the values from the `UpdateTimestampsCache` are not copied to other members of the cluster, so Hibernate looks at the old timestamps and thinks that a cached query is up-to-date. As a result newly inserted records are neglected. To fix it simply set `replicateUpdatesViaCopy` for the `UpdateTimestampsCache` to true.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. "replicateUpdatesViaCopy" is set to true. "eternal" is set to false. Still the query cache / updated timestamps cache are not invalidated/replicated. Any other ideas?

Comment: @lars First, check that replication works at all. If you use JGroups, see "Running a demo program" [here](http://jgroups.org/manual4/index.html). Note the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` part, if you can't run the demo without it, you should also add it to your configuration. Second, something else in your Ehcache configuration might be wrong. [Here](http://pastebin.com/KEYCZdqm) is an example that worked for me.

Comment: Got it, basic mistake. I had used "org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache" instead of "org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache" as name for the timestamp cache.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Ehcache configuration](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration.html)

Note that the eternal attribute, when set to "true", overrides timeToLive and timeToIdle so that no expiration can take place.

You have 1 eternal attribute setting to true. Maybe you can try setting it to false and see if it helps?

Comment: Queries are expiring, and then the inserted row is found. I have set up a 120 seconds expiry. then after two minutes the query will fetch the inserted row. However, I think EHCache should be smarter and find out that a new record has been inserted and invalidate cached queries on that table... or something similar...